# displayOption method of datasource not called in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: methods, datasource, dynamics-ax-2012

I was wondering if maybe someone had the same problem as I have. I have overriden the displayOption method on a datasource of a form in Dynamics AX 2012. This datasource is linked to a grid. I want records in this grid to have a certain background color when a certain condition is not followed.

I know the way to change the background color, so that's not the problem. The problem is that the displayOption method simply isn't called when the form is shown (I debugged and noticed it). Has anyone else had this problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Other methods of the same datasource are called without problems.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I am seeing... It appears that displayOption method is only called for the data source at the root of the form query. On the SalesReleaseOrderPicking form, I wanted to change grid colors according to values on the salesLine. InventReleaseOrderPicking is the root data source. I had to override the displayOption for that data source.

Comment: Can confirm that inverting the joins or moving the method solves the problem. But I've noticed that when my joined data source was still set to Delayed, the method *was* run. It didn't look correct so I wouldn't recommend doing it like that maybe someone can use this tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

"[When declared on a form datasource, display methods must have one non-optional parameter](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Display_method#Display%20methods%20on%20datasources)" (See *Display methods on datasources*).  Ensure that you have the parameter as a buffer of the same type as that of the datasource.

Comment: I'm much obliged for your answer, but I'm afraid it doesn't help me directly. I'm talking about the overridable displayOption() method for a datasource, not a method used for displaying data in a grid. The displayOption method provides markup for a grid (such as another backgroundcolor, ...) and is normally called automatically when a form is being runned, but in my case this displayOption method I've overriden isn't called at all.